# Proving upper bound for Bias of truncated sample mean

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, robust, probability-inequalities, bias-variance-tradeoff

We have data $X_1, \dots, X_n$ which are i.i.d copies of $X$. Where we denote $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu$, and $X$ has finite variance.

We define the truncated sample mean:

$\begin{align}
    \hat{\mu}^{\tau} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i =1}^n \psi_{\tau}(X_i)
\end{align}$

Where the truncation operator is defined as:

$\begin{align}
    \psi_{\tau}(x) = (|x| \wedge \tau) \; \text{sign}(x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \tau > 0
\end{align}$

The bias for this truncated estimator is then defined as:

Bias $:= \mathbb{E}(\hat{\mu}^{\tau}) - \mu$

And I saw the inequality:

$\begin{align}
    |\text{Bias}| = |\mathbb{E}[(X - \text{sign}(X)\tau) \mathbb{I}_{\{|X| > \tau\}}]| \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{\tau}
\end{align}$

But I am not sure how this was derived.

Comment: Is $\tau$ a real number or strictly positive number?

Comment: Yes I should of added this $\tau >0$

Comment: Do you know anything else on the distribution of $X$ ? Like the mean or variance?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=markov+inequality.  Chebyshev's Inequality is also helpful.

Comment: We just know that the data is iid with finite variance. I have been trying to work out how to apply markovs or chebyshevs to get the inequality.

Comment: Did you assume $\mu = 0$? Otherwise, how the "$|\text{Bias}| = |E[(X - \operatorname{sign}(X)\tau)I_{\{|X| > \tau\}}]|$" expression is independent of $\mu$?  Can you also provide the reference where you "saw" this inequality?

Comment: @Zhanxiong $\mu$ is the expected value of $X_i$, therefore we can write $|\mu -  \mathbb{E}[\psi_{\tau}(X)] | = |\mathbb{E}[X] -  \mathbb{E}[\psi_{\tau}(X)] |$ and then you can get $|\mathbb{E}[(X - \text{sign}(X)\tau) \mathbb{I}_{\{|X| > \tau\}}]|$. The inequality is given above proposition 1 in [this paper](https://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A31n422.pdf)

Comment: @DylanDijk Thanks for your clarification.  I added an answer below.  Only rank ordering of the two functions is needed -- it is simpler than Markov or Chebyshev as the inequality of interest actually does not contain "$P$", but only "$E$".

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks for the answer. I was wondering what you meant by "rank ordering"? Also I have asked a similar question to this one [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/612597/proving-upper-bound-for-truncated-difference), that I am struggling with. Thanks again.

Comment: @DylanDijk "rank ordering" is just a loose term: if $a \leq b$, then it is common to say $a$'s rank (ordering) is lower than $b$'s. There are more precise definitions of "rank" and "order" for a list of numbers, see R help pages of functions `rank` and `order`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
\begin{align*}
 & |E[(X - \operatorname{sign}(X)\tau)I(|X| > \tau)]| \\
=& |E[(X - \tau)I(X > \tau) + (X + \tau)I(X < -\tau)]| \\
\leq & E[|(X - \tau)I(X > \tau) + (X + \tau)I(X < -\tau)|].
\end{align*}

Now note the function $f(x) = |(x - \tau)I_{(\tau, \infty)}(x) + (x + \tau)I_{(-\infty, -\tau)}(x)|, x \in \mathbb{R}$ is dominated by the function $g(x) = x^2/\tau, x \in \mathbb{R}$ (draw a picture). The inequality then follows by taking "$E$" on both sides of the inequality $f(X) \leq g(X)$.

---

When $\tau = 2$, the graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are shown as follows:

[image]

```r
f <- function(x, tau) {
  abs((x - tau) * (x > tau) + (x + tau) * (x < -tau))
}

g <- function(x, tau) {
  x^2 / tau
}

x <- seq(-5, 5, len = 1000)
y1 <- f(x, 2)
y2 <- g(x, 2)

plot(x, y1, type = 'n', xlab = '', ylab = '', ylim = c(0, 3))
lines(x, y1, lty = 1)
lines(x, y2, lty = 2)
legend('bottomright', c("f(x)", "g(x)"), lty = 1:2)
```

Comment: I wonder if you can now show that the Bias is strictly bounded away from zero?

Comment: I have made a new question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/614189/is-truncated-mean-a-biased-estimator) now