# Is truncated mean a biased estimator

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, robust, probability-inequalities, bias-variance-tradeoff

We have data $X_1, \dots, X_n$ which are i.i.d copies of $X$. Where we denote $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu$, and $X$ has finite variance.

We define the truncated sample mean:

$\begin{align}
    \hat{\mu}^{\tau} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i =1}^n \psi_{\tau}(X_i)
\end{align}$

Where the truncation operator is defined as:

$\begin{align}
    \psi_{\tau}(x) = (|x| \wedge \tau) \; \text{sign}(x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \tau > 0
\end{align}$

The bias for this truncated estimator is then defined as:

Bias $:= \mathbb{E}(\hat{\mu}^{\tau}) - \mu$

In [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611794/proving-upper-bound-for-bias-of-truncated-sample-mean) it is shown that we can upper bound the truncation

$\begin{align}
    |\text{Bias}| = |\mathbb{E}[(X - \text{sign}(X)\tau) \mathbb{I}_{\{|X| > \tau\}}]| \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{\tau}
\end{align}$

---

I was now wondering if it can be shown that:

$\begin{align}
    0 < |\text{Bias}| 
\end{align}$

That is, is the truncated mean estimate biased?

Comment: It depends on the distribution of $X$ and the choice of $\tau$.  I believe in most cases it is biased, which can be verified by some simple simulations.

Comment: What does the AND operator $x\land y$ mean for real numbers $x$ and $y$? Bitwise AND? How is this related to "truncation"?

Comment: @cdalitz In probability theory, for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, "$x \wedge y$" is a commonly used shorthand for $\min(x, y)$.  Similarly, $x \vee y$ means $\max(x, y)$.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate my comment, consider first that $X \sim U(-2, 2)$ and $\tau = 1$. In this case $E[X] = 0$ and $E[\psi_\tau(X)] = 0$, hence the bias is $0$.

On the other hand, if $X \sim U(-1, 2)$ and $\tau = 1$, then $E[X] = \frac{1}{2}$ but $E[\psi_\tau(X)] = \frac{1}{6}$, which gives the bias of $-\frac{1}{3}$.

Therefore, if you are faced with a non-trivial statistical inference problem, I tend to believe $\hat{\mu}^\tau$ is biased (as unbiasedness requires $E_\mu(\hat{\mu}^\tau) = \mu$ for **every** distribution in the parametric family).  To see this more clearly, I suggest you tabulating a table of biases for the family of normal distributions $\{N(\mu, 1): \mu > 0\}$.  Of course, the question may have a more definitive answer if you can restrict the underlying distribution family to a specific one.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that if a distribution is symmetric with mean zero then the truncated mean will always be unbiased.

Comment: @DylanDijk That's true.  But as I stated, then it is not a "non-trivial" estimation problem.  If a distribution is symmetric with mean $0$, then its mean is certainly $0$, there is nothing to infer about.  But as a probabilistic statement, that's fine.

Comment: If the truncation is instead defined in terms of symmetric order statistics, as in trimmed means, the property stands for a distribution symmetric around its unknown expectation.